# Keeping an object inserted in NSMutableArray property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I came up with an idea for displaying the high score of a game and what I'm actually trying to do is basically adding two numbers to an `NSMutableArray` and checking the biggest between the two numbers the biggest stays in the array the other must be removed.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *highscoreArray;

-(void)displaHighScorelabel:(int)score
{
    NSNumber *point = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];
    [self.highscoreArray addObject:point];
    int highscore = 0;
    if([self.highscoreArray indexOfObject:[self.highscoreArray lastObject]] == 0)
        highscore = [[self.highscoreArray lastObject]integerValue];
    else for(int i=0; i < [self.highscoreArray count];i++)
    {
        if ([self.highscoreArray[i] intValue] >= [self.highscoreArray[i+1] intValue]) {
            [self.highscoreArray removeObjectAtIndex:i+1];
            highscore = [self.highscoreArray[i] intValue];
        }
        else if([self.highscoreArray[i] intValue] <= [self.highscoreArray[i+1] intValue])
        {
            [self.highscoreArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            highscore = [self.highscoreArray[i+1] intValue];
        }
    }
    self.highscoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Score: %i",highscore];
    [self CheckSomething:self.highscoreArray];
}
```

**The problem is:** the array only keeps one number in the heap. How can I keep it without releasing it? Since the next number I'm going to add will be at index 0 which basically means the previous number was released out of the heap.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, by the end of this method you will have an array that contains one object: - either an `NSNumber` with an int value of `score`, or, if it contained an `NSNumber` with a higher `intValue` than `score`, it will continue to hold that number. Seems like it might be more straightforward to just store an `int`, and before setting it, check if the existing value is greater. Also, what do you mean by "how can I keep it without releasing it?" - keep *what*? The old value it contained? Keep it where, for how long, and why?

Comment: He means if he removed it from an array he cannot access it anymore :)

Comment: I figured that likely - still doesn't answer where / how long/ why it needs to be kept. Does the old high score need to be passed to the `Checksomething:` method? Does it need to be stored in some history of high scores somewhere, and persisted? etc.

Comment: Carl what I'm trying to do is adding scores to an array(when? depends on the consumer), afterwards I'll be checking the biggest number"score" the lowest score must be removed from the array though.(in that case the array will always have have max 2 numbers because I'll be removing the lowest between the 2 eventually check the foregoing code in the for loop). About the method CheckSomething it is just for checking how big is the array! Hopefully now you understand.

Comment: @Oneill: Right, I get that. But your question asks how to keep a number after removing it from the array, and I'm asking, what do you need it for, because how to keep it will depend on your requirement. Also I still don't really see the utility of an array for this but I guess that's beside the point.

Comment: @CarlVeazey lets forget about the ifs/for loops for second 
-(void)displaHighScorelabel:(int)score
{
    NSNumber *point = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];
    [self.highscoreArray addObject:point];
}
lets say we have this method now every time I pass a number to the method, its job to insert the number onto the array.well it actually adds the number but the problem is the old numbers are just not on the array. do you ave any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If that's actually your problem, you are probably either never instantiating the array, or re-instantiating it every time an object is added.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `NSMutableArray` and use

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

At the index 0, all the data is going to move up 1 position, so the one in 0 will be in 1.

In case yopu want to store global values, you can try using `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Then I can start up i=1 instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

Other problem you might have is that you cannot remove an element of an array you are iterating through.

Best solution:
Create new temporary NSMutableArray as local variable and create a desired content in new one. After that assign temporary array to your variable.

```
 NSMutableArray* temporarySortingArray = [NSMutableArray array];
 //do your sorting / removing by iterating through self.highscoreArray and adding results to temporarySortingArray
 self.highscoreArray  = temporarySortingArray;
```

Btw. You should take a look at this NSArray method:

```
 sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]
```

With that you can solve problem much easier, just sort score and take top scores.

Comment: I'm not home yet I'll edit the code soon and check both solutions btw what do you mean by [NSMutableArray array] ? Is it a method ?

Comment: no I mean: tempArray = [self.highscoreArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]